# Why can't I save draft in contact email?

Tags: civimail, contacts, email

I am not using CiviMail but trying to email directly out of a contact record. The only options available are "Send Email" or "Cancel". My agency needs to be able to save a draft to edit and send at a later date. Is this possible or am I missing something? It seems that CiviMail only uses groups. I need a function to save drafts from individual contact. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Erin

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct that this functionality is missing. Workarounds that might serve you well include:

- writing and saving the draft as a meeting note for the contact, then copy-pasting into an actual email when ready.
- creating a new activity type that is called "email draft" and doing the same.
- using an actual email client, such as gmail, to write and save a draft, and when ready, send, bccing civiemails so that the email is logged in the contact's activity. (this will require setup of email-to-activity if it hasn't already been configured)

I hope one of these helps!